# http request in angular 2 getting called twice

Tags: angular, typescript

I know this question is avialable on the stackover flow and i belive me i had gone through it. Based , on that i found that there is no problem in my code. Although my rest api are getting called twice.

My Code snippet looks like:

**Component:**

```
    export class Component  {

        constructor(private _nService: NService) {
            this.categoryList = this._nService.getCategories();
            this.getMessage();
        }

     getMessage() {
        console.log('inside getMessagecomponent');
        this._nService.getNotifications().subscribe(notifications => {
            console.log('Calling Service...');
        });

     }
    }
```

**Service:**

```
@Injectable()
export class NService {

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

   getNotifications() {
        console.log('inside getNotification service');      
        return this.http.get(URL)
            .map((res: Response) => res.json());
    }

}
```

I have put the console.log in component and service just to analyze that whether the method is called from some other places or not or getting called twice or not.

I found the console.log in component and service are getting called only once.But, my rest api are calling twice by this request.

- I have tried .share() but its not working in my case.
- Also i tried to unsubscribe my call its also not working

Sequence in which my console.log are getting displayed:

- inside getMessagecomponent component
- inside getNotification service
- Calling Service...

PS: This is happing with all the apis in my project.

[image]

Headers:

```
Request 1:
----------------

Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, remember-me, x-dd-cust, x-dd-apitoken
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:8425
Access-Control-Max-Age:3600
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date:Mon, 20 Mar 2017 07:00:40 GMT
Expires:0
Pragma:no-cache
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Application-Context:application:dev:8085
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:DENY
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block

Response 1:
---------------

Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:application/json
Host:localhost:8085
Origin:http://localhost:8425
Referer:http://localhost:8425/dashboard
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
x-dd-apitoken:TOKEN
x-dd-cust:name

Request 2:
--------------

Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, remember-me, x-dd-cust, x-dd-apitoken
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:8425
Access-Control-Max-Age:3600
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date:Mon, 20 Mar 2017 07:00:40 GMT
Expires:0
Pragma:no-cache
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Application-Context:application:dev:8085
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:DENY
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block

Resposne 2:
------------

Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:application/json
Host:localhost:8085
Origin:http://localhost:8425
Referer:http://localhost:8425/dashboard
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
x-dd-dd:TOKEN
x-dd-cust:name
```

> UPDATE

I found in the developer console its not OPTION request as i can see 2 GET request in the network tab.

Comment: `this._notificationService` do you have any other service?

Comment: @Jai yes its a service used by my component

Comment: you have a typo perhaps.. constructor says `_nService`

Comment: @suraj sorry i have corrected this here but in my code its correct mentioned.

Comment: does `getCategories` call `getNotifications`?

Comment: If you have cross domain call. There there should be two call. One for `options` and another `get`. Options call check that cross domain call is allowed or not. Then actual call happened. Is it scenario?

Comment: @Rohitesh what does this `getCategories()`? do you really have this one too.

Comment: @suraj no its getting some categories of notification. Actual messages we are getting by calling this.getMessage();

Comment: @suraj no .  this.getMessage(); is responsible to get the notifiaction

Comment: Can you confirm from developer tools that there are 2 get requests in your network? Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: @echonax yes i have seen in the Network Tab in the developer console i can see URL getting called twice.

Comment: `PS: This is happing with all the apis in my project.` Can you please provide a screenshot from chrome developer tools net panel. I think this api call is cross domain call. That is why it is happening for all call may be.

Comment: @ParthaSarathiGhosh Screenshot added in the question

Comment: From your screen shot it is not possible to know the `method` of call. Please share the headers.

Comment: one request is for OPTIONS request and one that you are actually calling.

Comment: Your Component could be initialized more than once, hence the two calls.

Comment: @ParthaSarathiGhosh plz see the headers in the editied question

Comment: @ParthaSarathiGhosh please let me know if you need anything i am stucked here

Comment: I am not able to understand the problem here. :(. If you are using angular-cli please quickly create a different component and try there with ngOnInit.

Comment: @ParthaSarathiGhosh did you look at the headers in the editted question?

Comment: Yes I did. But still I did not found which method is being used in two different request.

Comment: @ParthaSarathiGhosh  ohh... :( but what you suspect is it related to OPTIONS request or PREFLIGHT request issue??

Comment: @ParthaSarathiGhosh i found the METHOD as GET for both the apis in the network tab of the developer console.

Answer (score 4):

"Sequence in which my console.log are getting displayed:

inside getMessagecomponent component

inside getNotification service

Calling Service..."

If your sequence is like this, you are not making 2 `get` requests

`getNotifications` will return an `observable`, it will not make a `get` request. Your `subscribe` method will fire a `get` request and if you are making a cross-domain request, one of your network calls will be the `OPTIONS` request.

Comment: but i tried this on other seed project there also i am requesting the URL in the same manner and there i can see only 1 request. If OPTIONS request are behaviour then why its not happening in other seed project? So, i am little confused here. Can we disable this OPTIONS request ???

Comment: @Rohitesh you are probably making a cross-domain request here. In your other project, you probably made your requests to your local environment like localhost.

Comment: @echomax No i am calling same URL in both the cases. Can i disable this type of OPTIONS request. I have also included the headers in the edited question for both request and response.

Comment: I have tried @CrossOrigin for my spring boot controller. But, its not working. Its to handle CORS support https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework .

Comment: @Rohitesh If you don't send the OPTIONS request you can't handle a cross-domain http call. I don't understand the problem. You have to make the OPTION call.

Comment: yeah that's ok like OPTIONS call but its hitting my service i mean the endpoints and making 2 db calls for a single request . Is this the normal behaviour???

Comment: @Rohitesh you are **not** making 2 db calls. `this._nService.getNotifications()` is returning you an observable, it is not making a request. The request is made when you call the `subscribe` method.

Comment: i had put System.out.print inside the endpoint and its getting printed twice. Does it not mean that my DB is hitting twice. Also, in the developer console i found that the METHOD type is GET instead of OPTION for both the duplicate enpoint also.

Comment: @Rohitesh In your question it says "Sequence in which my console.log.." if every line is printed once and you are making 2 get requests, you are making the 1 from somewhere else

Comment: i don't know how its happing becz both the application are running on my local machine where i am testing and there is no chance that from somewhere call can come and hit the api. also in my UI(angular 2) i checked from only 1 place my endpoint is getting called :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138591/discussion-between-rohitesh-and-echonax).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add share function of Observable

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/share';

export class Component  {

    constructor(private _nService: NService) {
        this.categoryList = this._nService.getCategories();
        this.getMessage();
    }

 getMessage() {
    console.log('inside getMessagecomponent');
    this._nService.getNotifications().subscribe(notifications => {
        console.log('Calling Service...');
    }).share();

 }
}
```